# Silent booting Linux from u-boot

Tags: kernel, boot

For security reasons I have to boot Linux from u-boot with all output hidden (silently) until a password is entered. I've configured uBoot to do this correctly using the `CONFIG_AUTOBOOT_KEYED` macro and can successfully boot silently.

The issue I am having is that when uBoot boots the Linux kernel and silent mode is enabled, it passes `console=` as part of the bootargs to Linux kernel. This is fine for silent booting, but I can't seem to find a way to re-enable the console again after bootup.

I've also tried to boot normally and append `loglevel=0` to the kernal bootargs which works for silent bootup, but again I cannot re-enable the console. I've tried:

```
dmesg -n 4
```

and

```
klogd -c 4
```

to try to set the Kernel loglevel back to KERN_WARNING (4) without luck. These commands work properly when I boot the Kernel normally.

The best guide I've found on the matter is [Silencing the boot process](http://docs.blackfin.uclinux.org/doku.php?id=silent_booting) on blackfin.uclinux.org.

Ideally I'd like to use uBoot's silent mode where it passes `console=` as part of the bootargs but still take input on the console and re-enable output when the password is entered.

Comment: An alternative to change the loglevel is to write to `/proc/sys/kernel/printk`. See `proc(5)` for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else runs into this issue I never found a good fix. I ended up hacking both u-boot and the linux kernel serial driver and basically checking if the password had been entered. If it had, I allowed the code to run normally. If it hadn't I just returned from the functions so that nothing was actually printed out on the console.

For Kernel I edited the receive_chars() function to look for the password (input) and transmit_chars() to mask output. I had u-boot pass the password in as part of the bootargs. If it was null, then the password was already entered and we ignored the special code. If it was a value, then we grabbed input chars via receive_chars() and compare them to the stored string from bootargs.

In u-boot I just used the CONFIG_AUTOBOOT_KEYED and associated default macros for the password entry. I then changed common/cmd_bootm.c to not call fixup_silent_linux() to mask the console= value and let the kernel deal with it as stated above.

Hopefully this helps someone else.