# Try to disable console output, console=null doesn't work

Tags: command-line, boot, linux-kernel, console

as mentioned above, I want to to completely turn off the console output, but putting `console=` or `console=null` in the kernel command line doesn't change a thing. When I enque `quiet` to the kernel command line it approximates this job, but I want to completely turn off the output.

So why is `console=null` not working, there isn't even an error message?

Comment: Do any of these work for you? http://superuser.com/questions/29666/silencing-linux-console-output

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17162/silent-booting-linux-from-u-boot

Comment: how is this even possible, if this seems to be a working method on other systems but of mine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U-Boot is doing exactly what it should (silencing the output) with the following command:

> #define CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS \
>
> ```
>         "silent=1\0" \
> ```

seems like this happens only on my system.

Answer (score 9):

#### 1. Using dmesg

One method would be to do so using `dmesg`:

```
   -n, --console-level level
          Set the level at which logging of messages is done to the console.  
          The level is a level number or abbreviation of the  level  name.
          For all supported levels see dmesg --help output.
```

For example:

```
$ sudo dmesg -n0
```

#### 2. Using rsyslog

Another method would be through `rsyslog`. The config file `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
#kern.*                                                 /dev/console
```

Changing this line to this:

```
kern.*                                                 /dev/null
```

**NOTE:** A restart of `rsyslog` is necessary, `sudo service rsyslog restart`.

#### 3. Using sysctl

Lastly you can control this at the kernel level via `sysctl`.

I suggest you alter your `/etc/sysctl.conf`. Specifically, you want to tweak the [kernel.printk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13019/1209) line.

```
# Uncomment the following to stop low-level messages on console
kernel.printk = 3 4 1 3
```

You can see your current settings:

```
$ sudo sysctl -a|grep "kernel.printk\b"
kernel.printk = 4   4   1   7
```

#### 4. Using silent

If you truly want to disable all logging, even during boot then change the string `quiet` to `silent` in the boot arguments to the kernel in GRUB, in `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`.

```
linux   /vmlinuz-3.12.11-201.fc19.x86_64 ... rhgb silent ....
```

Comment: Thanks. Even when I put the log levels to 1 or 0 it doesn't lower the output. BTW I want to disable the output since startup, not only when the system is ready

Comment: the silent command didn't work either, I'll try the commenting of kernel.printk as you recommended tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

After hours of searching:

Comment out the *.emerg line or change it to *.emerg /var/log/messages etc

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please [edit] your answer and explain what file you are suggesting should be edited, and show both the original line and what you want to change it to.

Comment: Edited answer to make it more clear.