# How to have a seamless custom JPG image splash screen when GRUB starts, the kernel boots, etc. until a GUI app starts?

Tags: debian, boot, xfce, display

**On a standard Debian, how to replace everything that is displayed at Linux boot by a custom JPG or PNG image, until a Python app with GUI starts?**

Is there a generic way to replace the boot messages display with a `CustomSplash.jpg` image, in a **seamless** way, with no flicker, for:

- GRUB (I already used this in `/etc/default/grub`: `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`, `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true` but I think there's still a *very* short GRUB splash screen)
- these log messages:

  [image]
- the start screen X11/Xfce4 (for now I have enabled an autologin like in [Automatically Login on Debian 9.2.1 Command Line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401759/automatically-login-on-debian-9-2-1-command-line/401798#401798) and I do `startxfce4` manually, but eventually I'll create a `systemd` service to start `xfce`)
- i.e. everything until a Python app starts (using Tkinter or wxPython)

For an embedded computer, I'd like to have only the custom splash screen and then the application. (The only thing I probably won't be able to remove is BIOS initial messages?).

Answer (score 6):

Concerning the boot process per se: You can try to use "silent boot" settings (see e.g. [here on the ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Silent_boot)):

- set `quiet`, *followed* by `loglevel=0`, on the kernel command line (`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` in `/etc/default/grub`)
- eliminate the cursor by setting `vt.global_cursor_default=0` on the kernel command line

OR

- use [Plymouth](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Plymouth/) to create a splash screen theme (a good reference on how to *write* the theme is [here on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/147769/1127743)

Relevant pages within the SE network:

- [Try to disable console output, console=null doesn't work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/117926/377345)
- [Ubuntu Server 18.04 hide/disable all boot messages (kiosk mode)](https://askubuntu.com/q/1043532/1127743)

... and probably others

Concerning your other points:

- The BIOS messages will be impossible to remove from the OS side - if you have a commercial project and order the hardware to volume, you can probably reach an agreement with the manufacturer/integrator to replace the BIOS messages with your company logo.

Answer (score 2):

- Add `splash` to the kernel parameters and use `plymouth` for the splash screen

OR

- Add `loglevel=0` to the kernel parameters.

To change kernel parameters edit `/etc/default/grub` if you are using the GRUB bootloader (probably)