# Completely disable any messages when booting Linux

Tags: boot, video

I want to completely disable the output of any messages on the screen when the system boots. `nomodeset`, `quiet` - don't work properly for me. Error messages still appear.
Ideally, I want to see a message on the monitor - "no signal".

The best I've been able to achieve is setting `console=ttyS0`, but I'm not going to use the serial port.

I tried to disable the framebuffer but that doesn't work either.

Comment: **console=none** causes the system to reboot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have a seamless custom JPG image splash screen when GRUB starts, the kernel boots, etc. until a GUI app starts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/597198/how-to-have-a-seamless-custom-jpg-image-splash-screen-when-grub-starts-the-kern)

Answer (score 0):

`loglevel=0` should disable everything except for kernel panics :-)

To switch off the monitor, add `setterm` to your `initrd` and run it on boot. This is distro dependent, and outside the scope of this question.

Comment: I want to achieve the behavior similar to the command: **setterm --blank force**

Comment: This is a completely different question/issue. You seemingly want to power off the screen while booting, only I don't understand why. Add what I wrote to the boot arguments and then add `setterm` to your `initrd` and run it on boot. This is distro dependent, so I won't say how it can be done.