# Seamless login in EndeavorOS

Tags: arch-linux, login, xfce, desktop-environment, lightdm

I would like to achieve a smooth login process where there is no visible black screen during the transition from the login screen to my desktop, similar to the experience in Windows 10.

Both Debian XFCE and Kali do this by default. The same image that is used on the background is the same throughout the whole process and there is no black screen or any sort of transition. Just login and the icons just start showing up.

I've checked the files inside these folders /etc/xfce4, /etc/X11, /etc/lightdm... but I couldn't find anything that was related to it.

I intend to use EndeavorOS XFCE with LightDM which has a very noticeable black screen after logging-in.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have a seamless custom JPG image splash screen when GRUB starts, the kernel boots, etc. until a GUI app starts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/597198/how-to-have-a-seamless-custom-jpg-image-splash-screen-when-grub-starts-the-kern)

Comment: Hello! Thanks for replying to me. It does not. I'm mentioning the time period between clicking on login and the desktop showing up. Rather stare at my background than some black screen. Thanks again!